# Parser OpenVPN log

Tags: php, sql

I am looking for days how to get the log information OpenVPN and put a php page. I am also unable to parser that information. can anybody help me? Below is an example of the log:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Wed Jan  7 16:06:56 2015
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
baba_jaga,1.2.3.4:1194,107322,492621,Wed Jan  7 15:59:23 2015
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
172.16.0.1,baba_jaga,1.2.3.4:1194,Wed Jan  7 16:06:54 2015
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,1
END
```

I found a code in php, but returned the following error: Notice: Undefined variable: status in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ z \ app.php on line 42

**I know mysql is wrong**

```
function parseLog ($log) {
$handle = fopen($log, "r");
$uid = 0;
$status;
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        unset($match);
        if (preg_match("/^Updated,(.+)/", $buffer, $match)) {
            $status['updated'] = $match[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^(.+),(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(.+)$/", $buffer, $match)) {
            if ($match[1] <> "Common Name") {
                $cn = $match[1];

                $userlookup[$match[2]] = $uid;
                $status['users'][$uid]['CommonName'] = $match[1];
                $status['users'][$uid]['RealAddress'] = $match[2];
                $status['users'][$uid]['BytesReceived'] = $match[3];
                $status['users'][$uid]['BytesSent'] = $match[4];
                $status['users'][$uid]['Since'] = $match[5];
                $uid++;
            }
        }
        if (preg_match("/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+),(.+),(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:\d+),(.+)$/", $buffer, $match)) {
            if ($match[1] <> "Virtual Address") {
                $address = $match[3];
                $uid = $userlookup[$address];
                $status['users'][$uid]['VirtualAddress'] = $match[1];
                $status['users'][$uid]['LastRef'] = $match[4];
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $status;
}
function sizeformat($bytesize){
    $i=0;
    while(abs($bytesize) >= 1024){
        $bytesize=$bytesize/1024;
        $i++;
        if($i==4) break;
    }
    $units = array("Bytes","KB","MB","GB","TB");
    $newsize=round($bytesize,2);
    return("$newsize $units[$i]");
}
$stats = parseLog("openvpn-status.txt");
foreach($stats['users'] as $user)
{
if($user['CommonName'] != "UNDEF")
{
   $result = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET updated =  '".time()."',          VirtualAddress = '".$user['VirtualAddress']."',    BytesSent='".$user['BytesSent']."', BytesReceived='".$user['BytesReceived']."', LastRef='".$user['LastRef']."'  WHERE CommonName='".$user['CommonName']."' AND Since='".$user['Since']."'") or die(mysql_error());
   echo mysql_affected_rows();
   if (mysql_affected_rows()==0) {
      $result = mysql_query("insert into stats (CommonName, RealAddress, BytesReceived, BytesSent, Since, VirtualAddress, LastRef) values ('".$user['CommonName']."', '".$user['RealAddress']."', '".$user['BytesReceived']."', '".$user['BytesSent']."', '".$user['Since']."', '".$user['VirtualAddress']."', '".$user['LastRef']."')");
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already got access to the information in the log. If you wish to put up a php page with the listed information all you would need to do would be to put a reference to the server log file in your php code and server it in the standard manner. If you wish to parse the information you simply need to write a script with the appropriate query strings and delimiters set. You will be able to do so within php though personally I would much rather use python.

Comment: About error code that I found ... Could you help me?

Comment: I do not know SQL enough only php but I can help you by tagging as SQL.

Comment: But more, the error occurred in a php variable, I believe that has no connection with sql.
Error: Notice: Undefined variable: status in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ z \ app.php on line 42